# Why does the latest "append" in my python doubly linked list have no effect?

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list, deque

This is part of my doubly linked list deque python code.

The 'appendleft' function written almost similar to the 'append' function is normally output. Why is the last 'append('apple')' code not output normally in the 'Group_of_append' function?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,item,prev,next):

        self.item = item
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

class deque:

    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name
        self.head = Node(None,None,None)
        self.tail = Node(None,self.head,None)

        self.head.next = self.tail
        self.size = 0

    def append(self,item):
        current = self.head
        new_node = Node(item,None,None)
        while current.next != None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = new_node
        new_node.prev = current
        self.tail = new_node
        self.size += 1
        return
    
    def appendleft(self,item):
        current = self.tail
        new_node = Node(item,None,None)
        while current.prev != None:
            current = current.prev
        current.prev = new_node
        new_node.next = current
        self.head = new_node
        self.size += 1
        return

    def print_list(self): 

        p = self.head

        while p.next != None:
            if p.item == None:
                pass
            else:
                print(p.item,end=' ')
            
            p = p.next

    def Group_of_append(self):
        print('Group_of_append')
        self.append('graphe')
        self.append('cherry')
        self.append('apple')
        self.appendleft('watermelon')
        self.appendleft('strawberry')
        self.print_list()
        print(" ")

deq = deque('name')
deq.Group_of_append()
```

the result is

```
strawberry watermelon graphe cherry
```

The last append code on Group_of_append, self.append('apple') have no effect.

While defining the 'append' function, I thought that there would be no output due to one more size being insufficient.

So, I changed 'append' function on deque like this

```
    def append(self,item):
        self.size += 1
        current = self.head
        new_node = Node(item,None,None)
        while current.next != None:
            current = current.next
        current.next = new_node
        new_node.prev = current
        self.tail = new_node
        self.size += 1
        return
```

But the result was same(still the lastest 'append' function doesn't print anything)

```
strawberry watermelon graphe cherry
```

Comment: Have you tried running this with a step-by-step debugger?

Comment: One thing I noticed: your `append` walks the whole list to get to the tail, (which would make sense for a singly-linked list with no readily available access to the tail). Even more bizarrely, your `appendLeft` walks the whole list backwards *from the `tail`* to get to the head. Both algorithms can be simplified to just use your existing `self.head` and `self.head`. In the process, you might end up cuttting out whatever was causing your bug, too.

Comment: Why do you increment `self.size` twice ?

Comment: Shouldn't the last element of the list always be `self.tail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your appends work fine. Problem lies in your `print_list` function which stops when `p.next` is `None`. Which means your last element will not be printed because its next is `None`.

All in all, your logic for this list is very strange and could use a lot of rework, it would make finding mistakes like this one a lot easier for you. For example, this iterating through the whole list when appending even though you have both head and tail readily available in the `deque` object.

Comment: If `tail` is meant to be a Node *after* the last "real" Node, then `append` *doesn't* work fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah, the logic is very weird and could be considered incorrect. But the item does get added to the structure and it can be accessed by traversing the list.